# FadeIn not working after hide in Raphael when using Id

Tags: jquery, raphael

This is not working:

```
<div id="draw">
        <script>
                    $(document).ready( function () {

                        var filler = {
                            'fill': 'white',
                            'stroke': 'white',
                            'stroke-width': '0',
                            'cursor': 'pointer'
                        }

                        var paper = Raphael(100, 296, 175, 5);

                        var rectangle = paper.rect(0, 0, 5, 5);
                        rectangle.attr(filler);
                        rectangle.node.id = 'rectangle';

                        $("#rectangle").hide();
                        $("#rectangle").fadeIn('2000');

                    });
        </script>
</div>
```

Nothing is shown. If I use only hide() it hides the rectangle. However, I want to fadeIn then, I tried to use #rectangle { display: none; } in my css file and then use fadeIn, but it is not working either.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong at all. I am not using remove(), but only hide(), so why it will not show?

The firebug shows that **style="display:none;"**; . Even when I remove the css for display none (**#rectangle { display: none; }**) from my css file.

It seems like after hide() you can not use fadeIn() function, but why?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `display:none` is given by jQuery to hide it.

Comment: yes, but I want fadeIn after hide and fadeIn is not working at all. Why?

Comment: It looks like everything stops after hide(). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add your CSS and HTML into a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: I can do fadeOut(2000) and it works but fadeIn is not working after using fadeOut. WTF? Is it some Raphael bug or what? I do not understand at all.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the div and document.ready that is all I have there. I have removed everything about #rectangle from my css so it has no effect at all. Still not working.

Comment: It looks to me like you're initializing Raphael the wrong way. And a script tag is not meant to be inside a div. The position of the script tag does not influence the position of the canvas.

Comment: But why is hide and fadeOut working and fadeIn not? I think the position of script is irelevant as long as I am using $(document).ready I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raphael does have only animation opacity for simulation of fadeIn and fadeOut. Maybe some future versions bring this to life. Just deal with it for now. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do that instead:

```
rectangle.attr({opacity: 0});
rectangle.animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrDGP/

Comment: Thanks this works, but I need to manipulate it later in my code with id and fadeIn is such a nice feature and I do not understand why it is not working when using Raphael.